# Does Struts action class violate SRP?

Tags: struts2, coding-style, single-responsibility-principle

As I can see, the action class in Struts 2 has multiple responsibilities.

First, we often put validation logic inside action class's validate method.
So when validation logic changes, we have to open class to modify.

Second, action class is responsible for making the result used by the JSP file. So when we intend to modify the view, we often have to modify action class and JSP together.

Third, action class has to know other classes' API to run the business logic and know how to handle the returned result.

At the end, the action class's code turns a mess.
Is there a better way to make the action class clean?
Or there's a book teaching how to write clean action class code?

Answer (score 0):

The action class is a simple POJO. You can clean it as you like it only needs to implement [`Action` interface](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html).

> The default entry method to the handler class is defined by the `Action` interface.
>
> #### `Action` interface:
>
> ```
> public interface Action {
>     public String execute() throws Exception;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> First, we often put validation logic inside action class's validate method. So when validation logic changes, we have to open class to modify.

That's your choice, but I wouldn't. In general, validation logic should be handled via the XML configuration. If you have complex validation logic it should be isolated in its own handler then used as either a custom validator or called by a thin layer in `validate`.

An S2 action is the veneer between the web layer and the business logic–this includes validation.

> Second, action class is responsible for making the result used by the jsp file. So when we intend to modify the view, we often have to modify action class and jsp together.

The action class *may* be used as the DTO between the business layer and the view layer, or you can use a separate entity and use the action to expose only that DTO. That's a necessity pretty much no matter what–again, the action acts as a thin layer between requests and responses. How you choose to organize it is up to you.

> Third, action class has to know other classes' API to run the business logic and know how to handle the returned result.

Well yeah. Anything that sits between requests and business logic needs to know what to do. That said, it wouldn't *have* to, it could just transfer data from the request to the business logic. The mapping to the business logic doesn't need to be hard-coded at all.

> At the end, the action class's code turns a mess.

That's your fault, not S2's.